# Need some suggestion in using VLOOKUP for my case in MS EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have 2 tables. First one contains the website url, City, State, Country etc which of those I need while emailing the persons. The second table has the vital "Email ids" extracted by software along with just the website urls.

But the Website urls might not be only one or so similar to the original one picked from the 1st table column.

[image: Click on this link to see my requirements in screenshot image]

Now, I would like to get the result in Column A only where some of the respective Column B value equals or almost equals to any values present in Column D.

I tried using IFERROR, TRUE/FALSE and VLOOKUP but of no success yet. Kindly help to achieve this.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `index match`, but as an array formula if you need to get address 'like' other ones. I take this as `google.com` and `google.com/tryme` should be the same.

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C, MATCH(B1, LEFT(D:D, FIND("/",D:D, 1)-1), 0)), "")}
```

Enter this using `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little about that formula? Also, do I have to enter the formula with keeping the cursor on A2 and drag over the whole A column or just with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER will work? Thanks

Comment: Its a normal `INDEX MATCH` formula, but in order to check "similar" websites, the `LEFT(D:D, FIND("/", D:D, 1)-1)` turns any address like `google.com/excelindexmatch` into `google.com`, by returning everything left of the `/`.

Comment: I am familiar with INDEX & MATCH well but the Columns C & D (both website URLs) won't remain in the straight ROW. So, the email id should stick with the Website url in the Column B, only if it is present in any Row of the Column D. Will it work?

Comment: Have you tried it? Column C are email address not website URL's, so from your example if column B is 'like' column D, then it will return the email address from columns C, to col A, in which case yes the above works. If this is not what you intend please provide more detail in your question.

Comment: This is what should happen as you said here "if column B is 'like' column D, then it will return the email address from columns C, to col A, in which case yes the above works. " .... But only weird thing is like if B3=D9 (no need for B3=D3 alone) and so C9 goes to A3. Moreover, with LEFT(D:D, FIND("/",D:D, 1)-1), 0)), "") there will lot many same values in Column D as opposed to single original value in Column B. In that case, what would happen?

Comment: It's not producing any results, Tim... I guess I don't even know how to use array formula CSE properly over here.  Could you please help me out? Thanks and if you could help me out with Skype, that would be so nice of you. My id is vjvpraveen

Comment: You will have to edit your answer with better examples of the outcome, you don't explain what "if this is like this" is, how similar can the address be? As per your previous comment, if `B3=D9` it returns `C9` in `A3`, thats exactly what this formula will do.